# Generic Extension method, how to get Type Name?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, generic-type-argument

I have created following generic method, **where I want to know the TypeName**, which is always coming as array of object.

```
public static string ToJson<T>(this T entity)
{
    Type type = entity.GetType();
    return type.FullName; // or  type.Name
}
```

SO if I pass an instance of class Employee, it is returning Object or array of Object.

My Call is like

```
Employee emp = new Employee();

emp.ToJson();
```

while debugging I am getting System.Object or Array of Object, but it is never array of object or object, it is always an instance of some class.

Comment: and the question is....

Comment: That is probaly because `entity` *is* an `object[]`.

Comment: The above should work for the actual type, `Type type = typeof(T)` for the defined type (if inheritance means those are not the same).

Comment: @InBetween: He is not saying they are the same so I think you are misunderstanding the comment (or I am).

Comment: @InBetween that's the point. If one wants the actual instance's type, one wants `GetType()` if one wants the signature's type one wants `typeof(T)`. If they were the same thing there'd be no difference.

Comment: @GianPaolo: my question was always there, Now highlighted in BOLD

Comment: @InBetween: No it is never, It is always an Instance of a class

Comment: @JonHanna: there is no inheritance, for any type supplied to T

Answer (score 1):

`typeName` is `object[]` because `entity` *is* an `object[]`. What other reason could there be?

A more interesting question can arise if your code were the following:

```
public static string MyToJson<T>(this T entity)
{
     var type = typeof(T);
     return type.FullName;
}
```

Err... isn't this the same, after all, the type of `T` and the type of `entity` are the same, right? No, not at all:

```
MyToJson((object)1); //will return System.Object
ToJson((object)1); //will return System.Int32
```

`T` is resolved by type inference *at compile time* with the information the compiler has at that precise moment in time; the argument `entity` is typed object, therefore `T` is inferred to be `object`. In your code, you are querying the type of the argument at *runtime*, therefore the runtime type is returned, which happens to be `int`.

Comment: Your call is wrong, MyToJson((object)1), its extension method not method.

Comment: And my problem is what ever I supply I get Object [] as type

Comment: @Trikaldarshi the method being an extension method or not is completely irrelevant. An extension method is a simple static method with some sugar on it, nothing more.

Comment: @Trikaldarshi and if `entity.GetType()` is returning `object[]` you can very well bet your bunnies that it *is* an `object[]`. The fact that you expect it to be something else is the problem, but let me assure you, `GetType` is not broken.

Comment: @Trikaldarshi that behavior is not reproducible. Until you provide enough information to actually reproduce the error you are experiencing I’m voting to close the question because there is not much we can help you with.